# Add all related content from entity reference with views

Tags: entities, views

I really hope someone can help me, because it's the last thing I have to do in this site, and I thought it would be more or less easy, but I can't get this to work.
Not even sure if this is the wright question, and sorry for some English.

My situation it's this one: 
I have two content types: Books and Authors. 
Books as a **entity reference** to authors.

In the node type Books, I want to display the book authors plus all their books.

As I use panels, I can do this simple or making a view.

But **what I can't do**, it's **to display all the author's books in that node**.

I can create a view with the authors and all their books, using views merge rows, to merge the books.

But if in the contextual filters I use the nid, all I get it's the same book from the node.

So I'm trying to create a attachment to display just the books titles from those authors, but honestly, I'm completely lost !

Perhaps someone could give me some examples how to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: Well, I've manage to get all the books with the attachment by adding in the contextual filter with the relation : Content:Nid > Content referencing Content from field entity reference to the author. However, now I still get a duplicate book node, ex: if the author only has one book, the book still shows....

Answer (score 0):

Click the "More" link in the contextual filter. That fieldset is collapsed by default but you'll find the option to make exclusions there. You may have to exclude the current node ID separately--not sure about that.